# sendBroadcast is giving permission denied exception

Tags: android

I had below code to refresh local media store`(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)`
Now suddenly this throws **permission denied exception**.

How do i solve this

Thanks

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,
                Uri.parse(MainActivity.BASE_PATH + File.separator
                        + _orderNo + File.separator
                        + Constants.BASICINFO_FILE_NAME)));
```

Comment: This Permission denial error is  occuring in Kitkat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That was never appropriate code in the first place, and it is now explicitly blocked as of Android 4.4.

Instead, [use `MediaScannerConnection`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaScannerConnection.html) or [`ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE) to request indexing of new files.

Comment: @ShailAdi: An app is not the operating system and should not be sending out fake system broadcasts.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should make a habit of posting your error logcat.

You probably are missing [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) permission in your manifest: